# [WARNING HTTP error codes detected during run: 404 (Not Found) - 1 times

Tags: linux, networking, sqlmap

```
sqlmap -u "http://10.129.15.49/dashboard.php\?search\=b" -- cookie="PHPSESSID=ld80r2ahkq6l2usoc3tecu2cd6"
```

[INFO] testing connection to the target URL
[21:10:33] [CRITICAL] page not found (404)
it is not recommended to continue in this kind of cases. Do you want to quit and make sure that everything is set up properly? [Y/n] y
[21:10:42] [WARNING] HTTP error codes detected during run:
404 (Not Found) - 1 times

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlmap -u "http://10.129.15.49/dashboard.php/?search/=b" --cookie="PHPSESSID=ld80r2ahkq6l2usoc3tecu2cd6"
```

or

```
sqlmap -u "http://10.129.15.49/dashboard.php/?search/*1" --cookie="PHPSESSID=ld80r2ahkq6l2usoc3tecu2cd6"
```

or

```
sqlmap -u "http://10.129.15.49/dashboard.php/?search/=b" --cookie="PHPSESSID=ld80r2ahkq6l2usoc3tecu2cd6" --force-ssl
```

I hope you didn't do anything illegal :)))